# help on cleaning up

Tags: updates

This morning I received a message saying that 16.04 was only partially installed. I did a partial install but it worried me.

Then I clicked the update software icon to get a message that it couldn't connect to repositories. That was obviously a mess, so I looked what I had listed. Owncloud was listed 3 times, so I could remove 2 of the lines.

It looks like I have loads of garbage but I would like to ask what I can delete. For example why would I want Cdrom for 15.10? I switched to 16.04, so what use would a CD be for 15.10?

I assume I need Canonical Partners and this is the only one I left checked.

It also looks strange that I have these disable on upgrade to xenial. I would guess that I could remove all of those. I am missing the owncloud icon on the top bar so that I may need to update ppa.launchpad.

I still don't know which one caused the failed to connect to repositories, check your Internet connection.

In any case I would appreciate suggestions on what I can safely eliminate to clean up the mess. Thanks, Ilan

[image: software updates]

Answer (score 0):

On the first TAB of that window check if you have the same thing (default installation with extra packages accepted during install):

[image]

**Download from** can be important too. Make sure the source is in your country (generally recommended to have a better speed with the repositories).

After try to relaunch  the update.

**Advice:** The best  way  to update is to  use the command line in a terminal as root:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```